# Is Abnormal Sweating a physical disorder?

Tags: sweat

I am an cyclist. I at least cycle about 30 km everyday. Other than, I love playing basketball. I play at least about an hour everyday. The problem is, when I am doing these, I sweat a lot than other guys. My shirt is completely soaked, when others are hardly sweating . Is this is a disorder? Is it hyperhidrosis? I am hoping I am not suffering from hyperhidrosis, because casually I am fine, no sweats. It just happens during sports or similar activities.

Comment: Do you get any symptoms of dehydration as a result of the sweating?

Comment: @Ivo Flipse, not noticeably, but slightly is obvious i think.

Comment: Same thing happens to me. To make matters worse, my sweat is slightly acidic. If I lean up against a wall I strip the paint off! Weird thing is, I never seem to smell bad after a workout, just sweat more than others. I've never worried about it.

Comment: @Sparafusile, Looks like we share a common property. I also don't stink after I sweat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are fine.  Check out the following articles:

- [Sweating: MedlinePlus Medical Encyclopedia](http://www.nlm.nih.gov/medlineplus/ency/article/003218.htm)
- [About.com Fitness Myths and Half-Truths](http://sportsmedicine.about.com/cs/conditioning/a/aa052001a.htm)
- [Ace Fitness Q&A](http://www.acefitness.org/fitnessqanda/fitnessqanda_display.aspx?itemid=279)

In all three articles sweating as a response to working out is normal.  In fact, the body adapts to sweat sooner the more fit you get so it doesn't store the extra heat your body is producing during exercise.

The important caution from all sources is to make sure you stay hydrated.  Considering the heavy cardio work you do, a sports drink may be more necessary than just water.

The MedlinePlus link does have additional symptoms to look out for that indicate you should talk to a doctor.

> Contact your health care provider if sweating is accompanied by:
>
> - Fever
> - Weight loss
> - Chest pain
> - Shortness of breath
> - Rapid, pounding heartbeat
>
> These symptoms may indicate a problem, such as hyperthyroidism or infection.
>
> Also call your health care provider if:
>
> - You sweat a lot or sweating lasts for a long time or can't be explained.
> - Sweating occurs with or is followed by chest pain or pressure.
> - Sweating is accompanied by weight loss or most often occurs during sleep.

Comment: Thank you so much for those references. I am little bit more comfortable with it now.